# SimpleDateFormat::parse() gets skipped

Tags: java, android

I'm quite new to `Java`/`Android` development.
I'm trying to write a simple Android app, and as part of it I need date to be converted from string to Date.

I have the following method:

```
private Date convertFromString(String birthdate) {
        String regex = "^(?:(?:31(\\/|-|\\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\\/|-|\\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?\\d{2})$|^(?:29(\\/|-|\\.)0?2\\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\\d|2[0-8])(\\/|-|\\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?\\d{2})$\n";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(birthdate);
        Date date = null;
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.UK);

        if (matcher.matches()) {
            try {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // <-- this,
                cal.setTime(format.parse(birthdate)); // and that line gets skipped by debugger step
                System.out.print(cal); // this line gets executed
            } catch (ParseException exception) {
                System.out.print("wtf??");
            }
        }
        return date;
    }
```

regardless of string value passed in to method it always returns `null`. When I step thru this code with debugger lines marked above get just skipped by debugger, and it wouldn't let me step in, as if `format.parse(..)` is just never called?

there's some debugging code left in method intentionally

*No exception is thrown during method invocation, I pass in valid data!*

Comment: the exception is thrown? rebuild the project helped?

Comment: Because it throws an exception...

Comment: rebuilt multiple times, no exception is thrown, if it was that easy, I wouldnt ask on SO..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You isn't fill date at all:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // <-- this,
                cal.setTime(format.parse(birthdate)); // and that line gets skipped by debugger step
                System.out.print(cal);
```

You set cal, but not date

2) I call this method with "24/11/1980" and matcher.matches() returns false, it's look like as problem in if(matcher.matches()), but debugger show you wrong line. After I change "if(matcher.matches())" to "if(true)" this method print "java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=343868400000,...". Why you not use just:

```
      private Date convertFromString(String birthdate) {
            Date date = null;
           SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.UK);

            try {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // <-- this,
                cal.setTime(format.parse(birthdate)); // and that line gets skipped by debugger step
                System.out.print(cal); // this line gets executed
                return cal.getTime();   
            } catch (ParseException exception) {
                System.out.print("wtf??");
            }
        return null;
   }
```

?

if you need some validation it'easy do with cal insead of reg pattern, for example:

```
             cal.before(new Date());
             Calendar beforeHundreadYears = Calendar.getInstance();
             beforeHundreadYears.set(1915, 0, 0);
             cal.after(beforeHundreadYears);
```

Comment: Why does it matter? my question is about `format.parse` invocation.. or lack of thereof.

Comment: Yes, you're right - the IDE is showing wrong line in debugger - it never actually goes inside `if` statement - maybe because I'm using bet version 2.0 of Android Studio

Comment: Can you update your answer to use Calendar validation, so I can accept it as correct

Comment: I add some Calendar validation example, it's what you want?